# Paginator table not paging after Jquery ajax query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I have a responsive table with [paginator](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html). In on load page, the pagination works, but after the Jquery Ajax event, which update the rows and data in the body table, the table do not is pagination.

**Table:**

```
<table id="tblFaltas" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead id="theadFaltas">
        <tr class="header">
            <th rowspan="2">
                Name
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="lnDia">
            <th>
            </th>                           
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tBodyFaltas">
            <tr>
                <td>
                     <center>
                      No data
                     </center>
               </td>
               <td>
                    <center>
                    No data
                    </center>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

And a select button which call the Jquery ajax function.

**Button with event `onChange`:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="day" onChange="selectDay()">
    <option>         
    </option>
</select>
```

**Function `selectDay()`:**

```
function selectDay() {

   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      cache: false,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      datatype: "json",
      url: '/home/getdays',
      success: function (returns) {
      $('#tBodyFaltas').empty();
          $('#tBodyFaltas').append($tr); // UPDATE THE BODY TABLE HERE
      }
   });
   $('#tblFaltas').dataTable(); // Call the dataTable pagintator
};
```

---

My doubt is: `$('#tblFaltas').dataTable();` works in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must reinitialise the dataTable completely after you have inserted new items :

```
function selectDay() {
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     data: JSON.stringify(data),
     cache: false,
     contentType: 'application/json',
     datatype: "json",
     url: '/home/getdays',
     success: function (returns) {
        $('#tBodyFaltas').empty();
        $('#tBodyFaltas').append($tr); // UPDATE THE BODY TABLE HERE
        $('#tblFaltas').dataTable({
           destroy : true
        });
      }
   });
}
```

The [**`destroy`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) option let you reinitialise an existing dataTable instance (if any) without conflicts.

Comment: Thanks @davidkonrad, but when I put `$('#tblFaltas').dataTable({  destroy : true });` the table doesn't paginating and in the console shows `c[b][f] is undefined`.

Comment: @LucasCosta -  How does your response looks like, ie `returns`? I was wondering that you have a JSON response but just are adding to `#tBodyFaltas` as it was `<tr>...</tr>` markup ...? Please show an example of `returns` ... There is perhaps a far better approach.

Comment: I put the slice of code here: http://jsfiddle.net/bn7ugp1f/ for facility your understanding.

Comment: @LucasCosta - Thank you! It is not correct markup. You need some row definitions, `<tr>...</tr>` for each row .ie `<tr>\<td >\<center>\Sem dados\</center>\</td>\<td >\<center>\Sem dados\</center>\</td>\</tr></tr><td >\<center>\....` browsers are forgiving, but dataTables need correct markup in order to function. Any chance you can fix that? Otherwise the response can be sanitaized before inserting - I give it a try.

Comment: hey @LucasCosta - here is an example with corrected header and so on, that let you insert the malformed markup into a dataTable -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zcdzz8so/** but you should **really** try to get the response right, i.e correct markup back from the server - or consider actually passing JSON back. The above is a dirty hack, just to demonstrate how you _also_ can insert data to dataTables.

Comment: @davidkonrar, you are right, this is a example, my real table is more complex (rowspan, colspan) and have many columns generating dynamic, i'm with problems with it, but I'm working in the columns header...thanks so much =]